# LibGDX / OpenGL ES: Rendering white sprite with transparency changes color

Tags: opengl-es, rendering, transparency, libgdx

I have a white sprite that I'm rendering with an opacity of 10% using LibGDX / OpenGL ES, but it has this slight green touch instead of just looking like a white plane. See this comparison between the one rendered with LibGDX and the one I added on top using Photoshop:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fic1hswyll58e7/screen5.png

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you include some code showing how you load the image and how you're rendering it?  Do you know what pixel format your screen and your loaded image are in?  Also, the order you are rendering your background and image in is important.

Comment: I second that, the green tinting you show in your image isn't something I have previously seen when using libgdx. Some code showing what you are doing to render the image, what you are doing before and after may help determine if something else is causing it. I have a suspicion you may be changing values other than alpha when rendering the image.

Comment: Already found the problem - the background image was rendered in the wrong pixel format - switched to RGBA8888 and everything worked fine. :) (well, basically everything has been rendered in the wrong format)